# jQuery autocomplete appendsTo wrong place

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I followed the instruction on their website and it works fine with inserting and selecting text, but it suggests the found matches not next to my input field.
How could I fix it?

[image]

```
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /;\s*/ );
};

function extractLast( term ) {
    return term.split(/\s*;\s*/ ).pop();
};

$("#id_authors").on('keyup', function() {
  $("#id_authors").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: "{% url 'autocomplete' %}",
    appendTo: $("#id_authors").next(),
    focus: function() {return false;},
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        terms.pop();
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( "; " );
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

I am adding the HTML below:

```
<html>

<head>... </head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col>
      <form method="POST">

       <div> ... </div>
       <div> ... </div>
       <div> ... </div>

       <div id="div_id_authors" class="form-group">
         <input id="id_authors">
      </div>
  </form>
  </div>   
    </div>  
  <script> ... the script above </script>  
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What does the HTML structure look like?

Comment: @ChrisBarr added it to the question

Comment: You are missing the styles. There should be a `position: relative` that's missing.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman that's generated by django form {{form.authors}}, but I can make the input field manually, where should I add "position: relative"?

Comment: Instead of selecting `$("#id_authors").next()` why not just put an ID on the element you want and use that instead?

Comment: @ChrisBarr without it doesn't show any suggestions anywhere at all

Comment: @Alina Without knowing where the HTML gets generated, can't think of where the `position: relative` will go.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman without auto html generating. I can use just <input id="id_authors">. And this is just an input field inside a <form>. But it still append the suggested box as in the screenshot.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] so that we can play around with it?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I added the "compressed" version of my template